# Print previous line after a pattern match using sed?

Tags: sed

I want to print previous line,every time a match was found. I know about `grep -A` and `-B` options. But my Solaris 5.10 machine doesn't support those options.

I want solution using only `sed`.

`Foo.txt`:

```
Name is : sara
age is : 10
Name is : john
age is : 20
Name is : Ron
age is : 10
Name is : peggy
age is : 30
```

`Out.txt`:

```
Name is : sara
Name is : Ron
```

Pattern I am trying to match was `age is : 10`.

My environment, Solaris 5.10.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$ sed -n '/age is : 10/{x;p;d;}; x' Foo.txt 
Name is : sara
Name is : Ron
```

The above was tested on GNU sed.  If Solaris' sed does not support chaining commands together with semicolons, try:

```
$ sed -n -e '/age is : 10/{x;p;d;}' -e x Foo.txt 
Name is : sara
Name is : Ron
```

#### How it works

sed has a hold space and a pattern space.  Newlines are read into the pattern space.  The idea of this script is that the previous line is saved in the hold space.

- `/age is : 10/{x;p;d;}`

  If the current line contains `age is : 10`, then do:

  `x` : swap the pattern and hold space so that the prior line is in the pattern space

  `p` : print the prior line

  `d` : delete the pattern space and start processing next line
- `x`

  This is executed only on lines which do not contain `age is : 10`.  In this case, it saves the current line in the hold space.

#### Doing the opposite

Suppose that we want to print the names for people whose age is *not* 10:

```
$ sed -n -e '/age is : 10/{x;d}' -e '/age is :/{x;p;d;}' -e x Foo.txt 
Name is : john
Name is : peggy
```

The above adds a command to the beginning, `/age is : 10/{x;d}`, to ignore any age-10 people.  The command which follows, `/age is :/{x;p;d;}`, now accepts all the remaining ages.

Comment: How can i do an opposite of this search?.Print previous line when "age is : not 10" ?

Comment: @ayrton_senna Easy enough.  I just added a solution for the opposite search to the answer.

Comment: What about printing a range from the line *prior to* the match, through the line matching the second pattern?  For example, the line _prior to_ RETCODE through the line _including_ the error MESSAGE.  I tried this but got an error:  `sed -n '/^RETCODE/N,/^MESSAGE/p' logfile`

Comment: To find the previous line of a pattern much is: `sed -n '/Age is : 10/{n;p;}' Foo.txt`

Answer (score 5):

POSIXly:

```
$ sed -n '/age is : 10/{g
1!p
}
h
' file
```

For printing previous line if current line does not match `age is : 10`:

```
$ sed -n '
$!N
/age is : 10/d
P
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

The `h`old buffer is good for storing a line *(or group of lines)* until some later test proves true. In other words, it is good for handling sequences of data which you want sequential but are not *yet* sequential - because it enables you to stick them together. But it also requires a lot of copies between the two buffers. This isn't so bad if you're building up a series of lines with `H`old commands - just appending - but every time you e`x`change buffers you copy the whole of one to the other and vice-versa.

When you're working with a series of lines which are already sequential, and you want to prune them based on context, then the better way to go is with
look-*ahead* - as opposed to the `h`old-buffer's look-*behind*. [cuonglm does this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206888/52934) for the second half of his answer already - but you can use that logic for either form.

```
sed '$!N;/\nage.*: 10/P;D' <infile >outfile
```

See, that will append the `N`ext input line following an embedded `\n`ewline delimiter to the current pattern space on every line which is `!`not the `$`last. It then checks if the line just pulled matches a pattern, and, if so it `P`rints only up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space - so only the preceding line. Last, it `D`eletes up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space and starts the cycle again. So throughout the file you maintain a one-line look-*ahead* without unnecessarily swapping buffers.

If I alter the command only a little you can see specifically how it works - by sliding over the file with a two-line window throughout. I'll add a `l`ook command just before the `D`:

```
sed '$!N;/\nage.*: 10/P;l;D'

Name is : sara
Name is : sara\nage is : 10$
age is : 10\nName is : john$
Name is : john\nage is : 20$
age is : 20\nName is : Ron$
Name is : Ron
Name is : Ron\nage is : 10$
age is : 10\nName is : peggy$
Name is : peggy\nage is : 30$
age is : 30$
```

That's its output. The lines which end in `$` are the result of the `l`ook command - which renders an escaped version of pattern space to stdout. The lines which do not end in `$` are those which would otherwise be `P`rinted. As you can see, the previous line is only `P`rinted when the second line in pattern space - the `N`ext line as just pulled in and which follows the `\n`ewline in pattern space - matches your pattern.

Besides the solutions already offered you, another way you might go for printing only *Name* lines preceding an *age* line which does *not* end in 10:

```
sed -n '/^Name/N;/ 10$/!s/\nage.*//p'
```

...which only appends a `\n`ewline followed by the `N`ext input line if pattern space begins with the string *Name*, and only `p`rints a line to output if pattern space does not end with the string *10* *and* if `sed` can successfully `s///`ubstitute away a `\n`ewline followed by the string *age* and all that follows until the tail of pattern space. Because there cannot be a `\n`ewline in pattern space except as the result of an edit command - such as `N`ext - the ensures that the only *Name* lines printed are those immediately preceding an *age* line which does *not* end in the string *10*.

All of the syntax used in the above answer is POSIX standard - it should work as written with any `sed` which supports the standard.

Comment: Does `\n` need in pattern `/\nage.*: 10/`?

Comment: @cuonglm - Yes. It ensures I'm matching the line just pulled in - the second line in pattern space. If I didn't use it I would print the age lines, too. You can see how it works really clearly with `l`. If you put a `l;` just before the `D` you'll see how it slides over the file - it advances two lines, removes one line the whole time.

Comment: The `l`ook seem to be broken in heirloom `sed`. It printed the lines as-is, not escaped sequence line `\n` or special like `$`. Thanks for `l`, it's worth.

Comment: @cuonglm - in heirloom it will work - there are actually three different `sed`s in the heirloom package. The default one will not escape newlines - but it will escape most other things. Print some other non-printables at it. Now if you use the Susv4 version you'll even get NULs - and it will escape the newlines as well. `l`ook is how I learned to `sed`.

Comment: Where can I get other two version? I only have [this one](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/sed.1.html), which interestingly call `l`ist intead of `l`ook :)

Comment: @cuonglm - yeah, I've heard it called that before, too. I might have invented the name `l`ook, or I might not have - I don't remember. The spec doesn't name it - it's just `l`. And so I like `l`ook. Anyway, you have them! I don't have heirloom installed on this running system, but... they should be in `/usr/heirloom/bin/posix/*/` or something like that. Or maybe you don't have them - I dunno how you came by the package. I've always built the tools.

Comment: Ah, I got it, I also built these heirloom tools, too. My test server is Ubuntu and I have 4, not 3 version: `/usr/5bin/sed`, `/usr/5bin/s42/sed`, `/usr/5bin/posix2001/sed`, `/usr/5bin/posix/sed`. Thanks for all the information.

Comment: @cuonglm - I [didn't invent it](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), I guess. That's where I *first* first started learning to `sed`.  Somebody should really rewrite that thing, by the way.

Comment: Efficiency aside, this is also better because it will work with arbitrary input (not only with the sample input where pattern is on every other line). If the input starts with a line matching `pattern` this won't print an empty line as first line of output and also if there are consecutive lines matching `pattern` this will print them (except the last one) which is correct as those are lines preceding a line matching `pattern` . ++