# Return previous line of all matches

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need to take the multi-line output of a program, match a string, and return the previous line of all matches.

An example of the output of the program:

```
$ jack_lsp -p
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
        properties: input,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out
        properties: input,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-1_in
        properties: output,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-2_in
        properties: output,physical,terminal,
$
```

I need to match, for example, 'input', and return the previous line of all matches. So in the example, the expected output would be:

```
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out
```

Here is what I have, but it only returns the first match:

```
$ jack_lsp -p | grep -B1 input | head -1
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your grep support the -B flag?

Comment: `head` will filter all of the output, not eatch match from `grep` individually.  You need to filter out the matching pattern itself.  `jack_lsp -p | grep -B1 input | grep -v input`.

Comment: See also [Print previous line after a pattern match using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206886)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the command you're trying:

```
jack_lsp -p | grep -B1 input | head -1
```

The problem with this is that `head -1` will return the first line of the *entire* stream of data that's piped to it.

Try this `awk` command instead:

```bsh
jack_lsp -p | awk '/input/{print previous_line}{previous_line=$0}'
```

It will print out the line before each line that contains the string "input". Here is the result for your example data:

```
user@host:~$ cat <<HEREDOC | awk '/input/{print previous_line}{previous_line=$0}'
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
        properties: input,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out
        properties: input,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-1_in
        properties: output,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-2_in
        properties: output,physical,terminal,
HEREDOC

firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out
```

For more information about this `awk` approach, see the following post:

- [grep - print line before, don't print match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943738/grep-print-line-before-dont-print-match)

You can accomplish the same thing using `sed`:

```
<!-- language: bash -->

jack_lsp -p |sed -n '/input/{x;p;d;}; x'
```

For more information about this `sed` approach, see the following post:

- [Print previous line after a pattern match using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/print-previous-line-after-a-pattern-match-using-sed)

In your particular case it looks like the string that you're matching against (i.e. "input") doesn't occur in the preceding line, so you can filter those lines out using `grep` as well, i.e.:

```
jack_lsp -p | grep -B1 'input' | grep -v 'input
```

You can also get the same result as the above `awk` approach by supplementing `grep` with some shell scripting, although the result isn't quite as compact:

```bsh
jack_lsp -p | (
    unset previous_line;
    while read line; do
        if grep -q input <<< "${line}" && [[ -n "${previous_line}" ]]; then
            echo "${previous_line}";
        fi;
        previous_line="${line}";
    done
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer grep because I have used it before and awk not so much (so if I have to come back to this code in the future, I will be starting from scratch with awk). But the grep solution isn't ideal because there is no guarantee that 'input' isn't in the first line.

Answer (score 4):

Using gnu-grep (available for all platforms and installed by default in most)
we can:

```
jack_lsp -p | grep -zPo '.*\n(?=.*input)'
```

where

- `-z` means "lines" separated by null (in fact it ends up slurping the full file) -- to have multiline patterns
- `-P` perl-like regular expression dialect -- to have lookaheads
- `'.*\n(?=.*input)'` a line lookaheaded by another line containing "input"

Comment: I strongly recommend against using `grep -P`. The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/grep.1.html) says this option is `highly experimental`, and from from my experience, the behaviour of `-P` changes with every release, so today I'm forced to have an old version of grep installed just to get some of my scripts working.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior, thank for. I have been using `libPCRE` and `grep -P` for many years and never witnessed that (I avoid using some dark corners of RE word ☺). Could you give an example?

Comment: I don't really have a newer version of grep to test (I had to hold the package on version 2.21), but I have in my notes that `grep -iP` with `(?s)` has given me different results after an upgrade. Also, since the man page calls it experimental, I would use it only on throwaway scripts!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just make it simple, and use `ex`, which has reverse-addressing:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/input/-p' | ex file.txt
```

For running it in a pipeline rather than on a file it looks slightly trickier, but works the same:

```
jack_lsp -p | ex -s /dev/stdin -c $'g/input/-p\nq'
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }
pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head $FILE

pl " Expected output:"
cat $E

pl " Results:"
rm -f f1
ed --silent $FILE > f1 <<EOF
g/input/.-1p
q
EOF
head f1
```

produces:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
        properties: input,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out
        properties: input,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-1_in
        properties: output,physical,terminal,
firewire_pcm:analog-2_in
        properties: output,physical,terminal,

-----
 Expected output:
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out

-----
 Results:
firewire_pcm:analog-1_out
firewire_pcm:analog-2_out
```

The ed command is simply:
1) find a line that matches "input"
2) print the previous line.

Run on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
ed GNU Ed 1.10
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl