# How can I match text at the beginning of a line and print the X previous lines along with the matched one?

Tags: shell, text-processing, text

I found a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/print-previous-line-after-a-pattern-match-using-sed), but it is not exactly what I want.

Let's suppose I have a text file like this:

```
[...]

age: 10
country: United States
city: New York
name: John

age: 27
country: Canada
city: Toronto
name: Robert

age: 32
country: Mexico
city: Guadalajara
name: Pedro

[...]
```

I want to match the line starting with "name: Robert" and print the 3 previous lines along with the matched result, getting only these lines:

```
age: 27
country: Canada
city: Toronto
name: Robert
```

How can I do this in the terminal?

Comment: Can the target name ever contain regexp metachars like `name: J.K. Rowling`?

Comment: @EdMorton In my case is just matching letters or words at the begin of a line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -B3 '^name: Robert$' input_file
age: 27
country: Canada
city: Toronto
name: Robert
```

Answer (score 6):

You already have the best way, just use `grep -B`, but you could also use perl in "paragraph mode". This mode is enabled by the `-00` switch and means that a "line" is now defined by two consecutive newline characters, basically a paragraph. This lets you do things like:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print if /name: Robert\b/' file
age: 27
country: Canada
city: Toronto
name: Robert

$
```

You could also do the same thing in `awk` by setting the record separator (`RS`) to empty (`''`):

```
$ awk -v RS='' '/name: Robert$/' file
age: 27
country: Canada
city: Toronto
name: Robert
$
```

The awk one also has the advantage of not printing an extra newline which the perl does.

Comment: One issue with the awk script at least is it'd produce a false match if `name: Robertson` existed in the input. Idk if the perl script has the same issue or not as I don't dare to guess at what any perl script does :-).

Comment: @EdMorton true, I guess we could use `/name: Robert\b/` or `/name: Robert\>/` or whichever awk will understand best, or even `/name: Robert\n/` although I suspect that will not be very portable.

Comment: `/\nname: Robert$/` would be portable if it's always a multi-line record with the `name` line at the end as the OP seems to be counting on, or if the `name` line could appear anywhere in the record then `/(^|\n)name: Robert(\n|$)/`. Using `\>` would be gawk-only, I'm not sure which awks support `\b` but those would both fail with a hyphenated name like `name: Robert-Jones` anyway,

Comment: You could alternatively add `-F'\n'` and then test for `$NF == "name: Robert"`.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the answer, but grep is omnipresent in almost all Linux distribution, I will go with grep.

Comment: @phantomcraft yes, absolutely. Grep is the better approach.

Comment: @phantomcraft awk is also omnipresent. Both grep and awk are mandatory POSIX tools and so must be present in any Unix installation to be POSIX compliant. Not so with perl.

Comment: @terdon if you additionally use the `-l` option while invoking perl then those trailing newlines won't apoear

Answer (score 4):

The format of your data is the same as the "recfile format" used by GNU recutils.  This means we may query your file like so:

```bash
$ recsel -e 'name = "Pedro"' file
age: 32
country: Mexico
city: Guadalajara
name: Pedro
```

To get the names of everyone aged 20 or more:

```bash
$ recsel -e 'age >= 20' -P name file
Robert

Pedro
```

Etc.

See `info recutils` or [the GNU recutils website](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/) for further information.

Comment: What I posted is just an example, I want to match texts and print the X previous lines for post-processing with another command (and now I can). Interesting this recsel, I didn't now it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the line editor `ed` we do it by first selecting the target lines(g//), then create a range around it(-3,.), and run a command on that range(p)

```
ed -s inp <<\eof
g/^name: Robert$/-3,.p
eof

## Gnu sed in extended regex mode
## collect 4 lines in pattern space then print the whole pattern space on match else clip first line and append the next

sed -E ':1;$!{N;/(.*\n){3}/!b1;/\nname: Robert$/b};D' file

# using the -p option to autoprint current record 

perl -00 -pe '($_)=/((?:.*\n){3}name: Robert\n)/' file
```

Output:

```
age: 27
country: Canada
city: Toronto
name: Robert
```